# How to properly check for whole numbers (value with no decimals being entered in)

Tags: javascript

I am trying to format a number as follows:
if no decimals in number then return 4 decimal (i.e. 100 would be 100.0000 and 0 would be 0.0000)
If there are decimals just return up to the last non 0 decimal(i.e. 100.000110000 would be 100.00011)

Below is my scrub function of which I load the value to be formatted into domtemp.value

The problem is in the "else if" below when checking for 0 decimals(or a whole number being entered). I never get there because the result always seems to be 0 whether or not I pass in 100 or 100.0011. Any ideas what I might be doing wrong with checking for a whole number?

```
function scrubAsFound() {
    var i;
    var length = 4;
        
    for (i = 1; i <= length; i++) {
        domtemp = document.querySelector('#equipment_asfound' + i);
       
        
        // Check for empty values 
        if (isNaN(domtemp.value) || (!domtemp.value || 0 === domtemp.value.length))
        { 
            domtemp.value = 0.0000;
            domtemp.value = Number(domtemp.value).toFixed(4);
        }
        else if (Number(domtemp.value) % 1 != 0)
        { 
             domtemp.value = Number(domtemp.value).toFixed(4);
        }
        else 
        { 
            domtemp.value =  parseFloat(formatAsFound(domtemp.value));
        }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padEnd

Comment: actually I think it's not possible to make 100.0000 as **Number** type....but you can make it as string and use it

Answer (score 1):

```js
function formatNumber(val) {
  let numberVal = Number(val)
  if (isNaN(numberVal)) {
    numberVal = 0
  }

  const intVal = parseInt(numberVal)
  return intVal + '.' + (numberVal + '').substr((intVal + '').length + 1).padEnd(4, '0')

}

console.log(formatNumber('abc') === '0.0000')
console.log(formatNumber('') === '0.0000')
console.log(formatNumber(0) === '0.0000')
console.log(formatNumber(2) === '2.0000')
console.log(formatNumber(2.1) === '2.1000')
console.log(formatNumber(2.00011) === '2.00011')
```